# Errors in simultaneous executions of GAS web app. How can I avoid concurrency problems?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a web app to track the working hours of employees at my company, the web app is simple, it first asks them to provide their username and a password, and then allows them to register their time of entry o their exit time. The data is then brought to a google sheet by adding a new row with the
information about the employee's registration to a sheet. The problem I am having now is when two different people execute the web app at approximately the same time, the sheet will then add one row with data and a second row in blank.

The code is pretty dense because it checks a series of things about that employee's previous registrations to make sure there aren't any mistakes, but I have tried and I can not optimize the code anymore, so the part where it adds the new row with data to the sheet takes about 1,5 seconds to actually execute itself. Is there a way to avoid these type of problems with simultaneous executions?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your whole script from your question, how about using LockService? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) and [Refs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+web+apps+lockservice) If I misunderstood your actual situation, I apologize.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.